# Find the solutions of : $(x^2-2)x^2y''-(x^2+2)xy'+(x^2+2)y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solutions of :

$(x^2-2)x^2y''-(x^2+2)xy'+(x^2+2)y=0$

I have to find infinite series form solutions,$y=\sum a_nx^{n+r}.$

I got the indicial equation : $r^2-1=0 \implies r_1=-1, r_2=1$

I got the general formula while $r=1$ is $a_{k+2}=\frac{k^2}{2(k+2)^2+4(k+2)}a_k$

Then , one solution is $y_2(x)=x^1\sum a_kx^k$ when I get $a_k$ using $a_{k+2}=\frac{k^2}{2(k+2)^2+4(k+2)} , k>0$.

How can I found the other solution when $r=-1$ ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

The last two terms combine to have a factor $(xy'-y)$. Having this in an equation gives you $y_1=x$ as basis solution. Check your recursion equation, you should get the same, for instance $k=0$ should give $a_2=0$ and then $a_{2k}=0$.

Find the second one by reduction of order as $y_2=u(x)y_1(x)=xu(x)$.

Comment: I checked my equation ,for instance $k=0 $ I got $a_2=0 \implies a_{2k}$ , $y=x$ is one of the solutions but how I get it from my equation ? I have to get $y=0+1\cdot x^1+0x^2+0x^3\cdots$, and I can't see how I get it.

Comment: In this case you actually need to evaluate the second "indicial" equation to get $a_1=0$ and thus also $0=a_3=a_5=...$